# Is democratic politics a force of unity?

Tags: democracy

Democracy involves competition among various political parties. Parties are partial and partisan. Their competition tends to divide any society. Is it correct to say that democratic politics is a force of unity?

Comment: I think the phrase you are looking for is simply that part of democracy is to protect minorities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be, democracy is about having political power drive from the people. Therefore people must unite to some degree in order to accomplish anything. The ideal is that consensus is built through debate and solutions are created that a significant majority agrees are generally positive. The counter is that it can be as effective or sometimes more effective to simply attack opponents of your goals rather than simply promoting your own beliefs. This sort of negative politics generally gets condemned by politicians, but generally only lip service.

Democracy starts to fail or at least appears to fail when people are deeply divided. It can be extremely divisive when there is no clear consensus or people are about evenly divided. In these cases the unity aspects tend to be ignored in favor of partisanship.

Comment: No society can fully and permanently resolve conflicts among different groups.